# Как найти координаты углов полигона пикселей?

Tags: python, pil

Есть картинка в формате .png, На ней изображен город в виде границ полигона.
Нужно найти именно углы полигона координаты которых в пикселях(в дальнейшем нужно их будет как то конвертировать в см или мм) размер картинки 652X639 (если это как то нужно). Использую библиотеку PIL в python, другие аналогичные библиотеки тоже приветствуются)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иначе говоря, преобразовать растровый контур в векторный?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586686/extract-external-contour-or-silhouette-of-image-in-python

Comment: Это типовая задача, которая решается в рамках графических драйверов и прочего такого. Вообще, на это есть соответствующий матаппарат.

Comment: @defaultlocale дело в том что контуры я уже получил!

Comment: Вроде нашел способ, существует один из методов Хариса для выявление углов, так же для питонистов, этот метод можно получить в библиотеке OpenCV

Comment: @Ali Там в одном из ответом упоминается [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours) из OpenCV. Насколько я понял, он как раз возвращает контур в виде векторов. Мне показалось, что это подойдет.

Comment: @defaultlocale эта картинка содержит пиксели, думаю что можно найти углы с помощью детектора и покрасить его в другой цвет и тем самым понять что эти углы данного цвета находятся по таким та таким та координатам пикселя!

Comment: @defaultlocale после как то конвертировать их в см мм или м ) хз как ))) покопаемся )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('screens/screenshot.png')
cv.imshow('img', img)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

dst = cv.dilate(dst, None)

img[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

cv.imshow('dst', img)

if cv.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
   cv.destroyAllWindows()
```